# Using Taylor expansion to derive error formula for midpoint rule

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

[The formula for local midpoint rule in the interval [-h/2, h/2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIPP0.png)

I cannot seem to find an answer to how this is done anywhere (including my course notes).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the Taylor expansion? With logic, you know the midpoint applies to some $x$-value, namely $\pm h/2$. $hf(0)$ just constructs a rectangle going from each midpoint $-h/2$ to $h/2$ with height $f(0)$.

Comment: Yes I need the taylor expansion. My professors notes don't have the steps on how to do this.

Comment: Here's a graphical example I created: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ysd91qdzhv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $$g(h)=\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}f(x)dx-hf(0)$$ and compute
$$
g(0)=0\\
g'(h)=\frac12(f(h/2)+f(-h/2))-f(0)\implies g'(0)=0\\
$$
etc. to find the Taylor expansion of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Put
$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+x^2f''(0)/2+...
$
so
$\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}f(x)dx
=hf(0)+h^3f''(0)/(2*3*8)+...
$.